# How can I configure a nix pkg priority for ghcWithPackages (in code)

Tags: nix

I am running on nixOS.  As a user, I install xmonad-with-packages & ghc-with-packages.  I have a configuration file and overlays to achieve this, but I regularly hit conflicts:

```
error: packages '/nix/store/jzjxvm4kll3b2pw7plhksgl1jxvwnkw8-xmonad-with-packages-8.6.4/share/man/man1/ghc.1.gz' and '/nix/store/dnk4znsf8avwjalj350wj59vznpzcihl-ghc-8.6.4-with-packages/share/man/man1/ghc.1.gz' have the same priority 5; use 'nix-env --set-flag priority NUMBER INSTALLED_PKGNAME' to change the priority of one of the conflicting packages (0 being the highest priority)
```

I can use `nix-env --set-flag priority` to resolve this, but

1. It seems to be erratic - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I'd like to say I'm being inconsistent about usage, but I don't believe I am.  For example, with the error above, I run

   ```
   nix-env --set-flag priority 4 ghc-8.6.4-with-packages
   setting flag on 'ghc-8.6.4-with-packages'
   ```

   ...and then the re-running nix-env -i, I see the same error :-(
2. Whenever I change host (far too often), I have to run it again, which is annoying, but moreover leads to the sort of potential inconsistency that I am striving to avoid by using nix.

I'd really like to configure the priorities in my overlays (or `config.nix`), but how do I do that?  My `overlays/myHaskellEnv.nix` looks like this:

```
self: super: {
  myHaskellEnv = self.haskellPackages.ghcWithHoogle
                     (haskellPackages: with haskellPackages;
                      [ aeson ... ])
}
```

my `overlays/myXmonad.nix` like this:

```
self: super: {
  myXmonad = super.xmonad-with-packages.override {
    packages = hPkgs: with hPkgs; [ xmonad-contrib ];
  };
}
```

and my `config.nix` like this:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with nixpkgs;
{
  inherit myXmonad myHaskellEnv;
}
```

Any help or pointers gratefully recieved!

Comment: Perhaps xmonad's should be wrapped by a script in a separate derivation that adds the necessary environment variables, but, being just a script, doesn't expose all its dependencies' files to the user profile.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll see if I can make that work.  Thanks,